# Python: Extracting multiple values from dict

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list

```
x = json.loads(y)
z1 = (x[0][0])
z2 = (x[0][1])
z3 = (x[0][2])
z4 = (x[0][3])
```

etc...

How do we **check** if [4],[5],[6] exists in dict, then print/assign the result if it does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Antonio Margaretti indicated, you shall use x.get('key'). Your full code will be:

```
x = json.loads(y)
z1 = (x[0][0])
z2 = (x[0][1])
z3 = (x[0][2])
z4 = (x[0][3])

for i in (4,5,6):
    k= x[0].get(i)
    if k is not None:
        print(k)
```

Comment: What about assigning them to increasing z-variables?

Comment: You can use:
`globals()['z'+str(i)]=k`
however this is not recommended in general. You would better use a dictionary z and assign the variables as items of this dictionary: z[4]=k, z[5]=5, etc

Comment: AttributeError("'list' object has no attribute 'get'")?

Comment: This means that x[0] is a list not a dict. In this case you can just loop through the lenght of this list:
`for i in range(len(x[0])):
    globals()['z'+str(i)]=x[0][i]`

Comment: Its kind of running through the list wierdly (with print statement inside the for loop). #print(globals()['z'+str(i)])
Is there something im missing with assigning to variables?

Comment: Have you assigned the value to global() before printing it?

Comment: How can we accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `x.get("key")` where x is your dict. So if  such key presented in your dict the data will be returned, else you will get None.

Small example:

```
data = x.get("some_key")
if data is not None:
    print(data)
```